# Artik710 - Playing through I2S without audio-codec driver

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, alsa, soundcard

I have an Artik710 Module on a custom board.
The Artik710 OS is fedora.

The board consists TAS2505, connected to the Artik with I2S,
and the TAS2505 is also connected to a stm32 micro-proccesor using SPI, which I am using to initialize.

I would like to configure a soundcard that plays through the I2S without using an audio-codec driver
(As the Artik710 is NOT connected to the TAS2505 using I2C/SPI).

Is there any way I can do that?